# How to change the pointer address of a Tobject variable?

Tags: delphi

I have an `Tobject` A. This Tobject is linked in several place (ex B := A); I want to replace A by C and **make also that B will now be egal to C**. How can I say that now A will point to C and thus B will also point to C ?

Comment: I am afraid that you need to make your question a bit clearer and specify under what constraints that code must be working.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could hope to do this would be to introduce an extra layer of indirection. At the moment `A` and `B` are values that hold two distinct copies of an address. You'd need to change the values in both `A` and `B` which I believe you are not able to do.

What you would need to do instead is declare `A` and `B` to be pointers to `TObject`, and make them point to the same variable holding the reference to `TObject`.

```
var
  obj: TObject;
  A, B: ^TObject;
...
obj := ...
A := @obj;
B := @obj;
```

Later on you can modify `obj`, and since `A` and `B` both refer to the same `TObject` variable `obj`, they would both see that change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code design. You need some kind of indirection. You can do it with pointers like David explained, or you can use an intermediate object; let's call it Provider. The Provider exposes an Object property. You create a Provider and pass it to several parts of your code. The users of the Provider access the Object property when they need the object.

At any time, you can assign a new Object to the Provider. After that, the users of the Provider will see the new object.

A benefit of that solution over simple pointers is that you can add any methods and properties to the Provider, which can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure Test(Sender:TObject);
var
 A,B,C : TObject;
 D,E : TObject;
begin
 A := C;
 B := C;

// if you want to keep variable A and B's original values then:

 D := A;
 E := B;

 A := C;
 B := C;

end;
```

Comment: I can't touch B :( the variable is outside my scope

Comment: @loki - If you can't touch B, what you are asking is not how to change the pointer address of an object variable but how to change the instance address of an object. You can't do that.